# Connecting via SSH with RSA using PHPSECLIB

Tags: php, ssh, rsa, phpseclib

I am learning how to use the 'phpseclib' library.

I have successfully managed to connect via SSH using the username/password combo.

I want to connect now using a private key, but I can't seem to be able to do it. Let me explain how I have gone about this and hopefully someone can point me to the errors of my way.

```
<?php

use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

include('vendor/autoload.php');

define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', SSH2::LOG_COMPLEX);

$ssh = new SSH2('MYIP');
$rsa = new RSA();

$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(RSA::PUBLIC_FORMAT_OPENSSH);

extract($rsa->createKey(2048));

file_put_contents('privatekey', $privatekey);

if($rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey')))
{
    echo('Key loaded');
} else {
    throw new Exception('Key not loaded');
}


if($ssh->login('chris', $rsa))
{
    echo('Connected');
} else {
    echo $ssh->getLastError();
    throw new Exception('Not Connected');
}
```

As you can see, I set the public key format to 'openssh' and then create the key. Using the values created by the `createKey` method I put that key in a file called 'privatekey' (no extension, but unsure if needed as it's just text). Then the normal, loading the key and using it as a value in the login.

I've used the official docs (which aren't great) and Google'd around and I've not had much luck with either.

The output of the `getLastError` is:

> SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE: publickey,password

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create key pairs all day on the client side but unless the public part of the key pair you generated is in the `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file then it's not going to matter. And if you're creating the keys and trying to connect with them all in the same script...  it's unlikely they're going to be in that file.

In this particular case you should load a private key whose corresponding public key is already in the `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Load that with `$rsa->loadKey(...)` and /then/ try to use that RSA object in SSH's login method.

Comment: Ha, looks like I'd of got it then with this post. While I did figure it out on my own, I shall mark this as correct as it's exactly what I needed to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out myself.

My own stupidity...

I hadn't put the `$publickey` in the `authorized_keys` file.

To be fair it's not like their's much *recent* documentation about this library, sadly.

Thanks to @PoX for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct I think you are getting this error because you don't have ssh server configured right.

Check in `sshd_config`

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Also make sure you have correct privileges on `/home/chris/.ssh/`
If you are keeping your `authorized_keys` somewhere else you need to configure that in `sshd_config` as well

```
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and permissions

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I do have both of those settings in my `sshd_config` already. My private key file is in my regular 'html' folder with all my other site related stuff - should it be in the '.ssh' folder? Also I changed the permissions of the file to 600, but nothing changed.

Comment: yes they should be under `~/.ssh/` added to my answer as well

Comment: Hmmm... so I moved the 'privatekey' file to that location, but it's still showing the same errors.